# Getting all Images in Android

Tags: android, android-storage

I am building a photo vault where users can hide their photos.
I write the following code which traverses through all the directories (except the hidden one) and creates a report mentioning the number of images with directory name and file(images) path.

It works fine and does its job but the problem here is the amount of time it takes to execute.

I run it on my OnePlus 7T with 128 GB Storage and 52% used it takes almost 30-40 seconds to get all the images. That is an insane amount of time for a user to wait every time they want to add an image to the vault.

I want to know what optimization could be made here so that its speed gets optimized. I have tested other similar applications and they are doing it in a snap.

Please let me know if you can help.

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalTime::class)
private fun getFiles(): List<MyFileModel> {
    val list = mutableListOf<MyFileModel>()

    val time = measureTime {
        Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().listFiles()?.forEach {file->
            if (file.isDirectory) {
                openDirectory(file)
            } else if (file.isImage) {
                addImage(file)
                Log.i(
                    TAG,
                    "getFiles: image: ${file.name}\nParent File: ${file.parentFile}\nParent: ${file.parent}"
                )
            }
        }
    }
    Log.i(
        TAG,
        "getFiles: took ${time.inWholeHours}h : ${time.inWholeMinutes}m : ${time.inWholeSeconds}s"
    )
    map.keys.forEach {
        Log.i(TAG, "getFiles: There are ${map[it]?.size} images in $it directory")
    }
    return listOf()


}



private fun addImage(file: File) {
    val parentPath = file.parent ?: throw Exception("Could not add file as image. File: $file")
    var folderName: String? = null
    if (parentPath == FileUtils.ROOT_ADDRESS.path) {
        folderName = "STORAGE"
        //File is in the home directory
    } else {
        folderName = parentPath.substring(parentPath.lastIndexOf("/") + 1)
    }
    val files: MutableList<File>? = map[folderName]
    if (files.isNullOrEmpty()) {
        map[folderName] = mutableListOf(file)
    } else {
        files.addIfNotAlreadyAdded(file)
    }
//        Log.i(TAG, "addImage: map: $map")
}

//
private fun openDirectory(file: File) {
    Log.i(TAG, "getFiles: FILE: ${file.absolutePath}")
    if (file.isHidden) return
    if (file.isImage) {
        addImage(file)
        return
    }
    if (file.isDirectory) {
        file.listFiles()?.forEach {
            Log.i(TAG, "openDirectory: file.listFiles().forEach : file: $it")
            if (it.isImage) {
                addImage(it)
            }
            if (it.isDirectory) {
                openDirectory(it)
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Here is the extensions function that checks if the file is an image or not.

```
val File.isImage: Boolean
get() {
    val fileName = this.name
    val lasIndexOfDot = fileName.lastIndexOf(".")
    if (lasIndexOfDot == -1) {
        //This means that the file got no extension
        return false
    }
    val extension = fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf(".") + 1).lowercase()

    return extension.equals("png") ||
            extension.equals("jpeg") ||
            extension.equals("jpg") ||
            extension.equals("gif")
}
```

Thank you :)

Comment: `30-40 seconds to get all the images. ` How many images? 100? 1000? 10000? 100000?

Comment: `That is an insane amount of time for a user to wait every time they want to add an image to the vault.` Why would you execute that code every time then!

Comment: `a photo vault where users can hide their photos. I` Could you explain what that would be. Or how that would be possible? As i have no idea where you are up to.

Comment: @blackapps I think somewhere between 5K-10K

Comment: Because there could be more pictures added or deleted at any time. So whenever the user presses the add button, it needs to show all the images that are currently available on the storage.

Comment: I do not understand a word. Sorry.

Comment: Like a secret vault where you can store some images. These won't be shared with the other apps. And then you put a password on the app to access those hidden photos.

Comment: Okay let me simplify it, say I want to make a gallery app and the app needs to show all the images on phone storage with their album (folder) name. And for that purpose, I need to traverse through all the files available on the device storage, check if they are images, and then add them to a map. Now every time the user opens the app, it must show up-to-date content.

Comment: You can query the media store for all images. Why dont you? And i still have no idea how you could hide image files. And also not why you would like to do that. Which user does want that not all images on the device are visible?

Comment: You are right I can query the images via content provider and I tried that too earlier. But 1: it only provides images, not their absolute path, 2: I am not able to delete/move images because of scopped storage.
That is why I can not continue using that. 

Say there are some private pictures that you don't want others to see even if they have your phone, that's the use case of this application

I haven't completely figured it out yet but on post android 11 devices, moving images to the app's private directory would do the magic.

Comment: Of course you can delete and move files too then if you are permitted to do so. And i wonder why you talk about scoped storage as files in scoped storage locations are not scanned by the media store.

Comment: Okay, so I want to move a selected image(s) using a content provider to the app's private directory. Can you tell me what permission I need and what operations would help me do that?

Comment: You do not need a content provider (dont talk about a content provider is you mean using the mediastore) to create files in app specific directory. Just use File class and FileOutputStream class. Further you suddenly talk about a selected image and i have no idea how you let the user select an image.

Comment: In order to move the pictures to App-Specific Directory, the user needs to select image(s) first.

Comment: I am sorry if I am not being able to explain this properly. So if you got few minutes to spare for me then please consider downloading this app here: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hld.anzenbokusucal I just want a clone of this app.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I was able to do that by implementing the Content Provider.
Going through all files and folders in the storage and then checking each file if it is an image or not and that too by looking at the file extension. It was a set of terrible ideas.
But in the end, this is how we learn. :)